# Excel - How to reformat nested table?

Tags: excel, vba

I have exported excel table like that
[image]
but i need another format like that:
00008BN07    item1  subitem1  2,000  6 872,320
00008LN02A  item2  subitem1  2,000  10 099,340

.....
020876071  item5  subitem1  1,000  294,260
020876071  item5  subitem2  2,000  294,260
020876071  item5  subitem3  3,000  294,260
How I can reformat first table to second view? Mbe some simple vba script?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the columns are A, B, and C, for name, item, and subitem respectively, try this code.
It makes not claims to try to be optimized.
When it has run, sort on column C, and delete all the junk that does not contain "SubItem" in column C.

```
Sub FillTable()
    Dim lRowCurr As Long
    Dim lRowColA As Long
    Dim lRowColB As Long

    lRowCurr = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

    Do
        If InStr(1, Cells(lRowCurr, 3), "subitem") Then
            lRowColA = Cells(lRowCurr, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            lRowColB = Cells(lRowColA, 2).End(xlDown).Row

            Cells(lRowCurr, 1) = Cells(lRowColA, 1)
            Cells(lRowCurr, 2) = Cells(lRowColB, 2)
        End If

        lRowCurr = lRowCurr - 1
    Loop While lRowCurr > 0
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks! but i have really misc data at column C (not contain subitem string), And can you write code for deleting junk rows (i have about > 1000 rows and if i going to do it manually i will die :)

Comment: You can replace the line IF INSTR(...) THEN with IF CELLS(.,.).VALUE <> "".  To delete the junk, you just need to sort the data on the subitem column, then highlight and delete the not contiguous range with no subitems - 10 seconds of work.